# Why does MATLAB's rgb2hsv return wrong Hue values?

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, colors

Consider the following image:

[image]

The below MATLAB code returns a histogram of the Hue values:

```
img1 = imread('img.png');  
img1(img1<1) = 0;
%
img_hsv = rgb2hsv(img1);
hue_img = img_hsv(:,:,1);
array = hue_img(hue_img > 0.1);
histfit(array, 20)
```

[image: MATLAB output]

It returns wrong Hue values, but the equivalent code in Python returns the correct values.

```
import cv2 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from skimage import data
from skimage.color import rgb2hsv

img = cv2.imread(r"img.png") 
rgb_img = img 
hsv_img = rgb2hsv(rgb_img) 
hue_img = hsv_img[:, :, 0] 
hue_img[np.where(hue_img > 0.1)] 
array = hue_img[np.where(hue_img > 0.1)] 
plt.hist(array,bins=100)
```

[image: Python output]

By using a color picker tool in any image editing software, we can see that the correct Hue value is about 50 out of 100 or 0.5 out of 1.

[image: Screenshot]

How we can get correct Hue values from MATLAB's `rgb2hsv`?

Comment: Thank you for comment, but this Python code surprisingly returns correct hue values.

Comment: @HansHirse Thank you very much for clarifying this point. And another strange problem: Python's histogram is a mirror of Matlab's histogram. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several issues here, which lead to false conclusions.

In the shown (Photoshop?) screenshot, the Hue value is **51°**, not **51%**. Hue values range from 0° to 360°, cf. the [Wikipedia article on the HSV colorspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Basic_principle). So, a Hue value of **51°** equals **14.17%**, which is in accordance to the shown MATLAB histogram.

So, it's not the MATLAB code, which is wrong, but the Python code!

OpenCV (`cv2`) per default uses BGR color ordering, so for `img = cv2.imread(r"img.png")`, we get `img` with BGR color ordering. Now, `hsv_img = rgb2hsv(rgb_img)` is used, where `skimage.color.rgb2hsv` awaits an image with RGB color ordering, which leads to the erroneous Python results.

Here's a possible fix (notice, your diagram shows `bins=20`):

```py
img = cv2.imread(r"img.png")
rgb_img = img[:, :, [2, 1, 0]]                  # BGR to RGB
hsv_img = rgb2hsv(rgb_img)
hue_img = hsv_img[:, :, 0]
array = hue_img[np.where(hue_img > 0.1)]
plt.hist(array,bins=20)                         # 20 instead of 100
```

That'd be the corrected Python output:

[image: CorrectedPython output]

We see, it's quite comparable to the MATLAB output.

Hope that helps!

---

**EDIT:** Alternatively, use `skimage.io.imread` instead of `cv2.imread`. Then, there's no need for any conversion, since `skimage.io.imread` uses RGB color ordering per default.

Comment: merci beaucoup. By using "skimage.io.imread" we also get an image in BGR. Is there any python packages that read images in RGB?

Comment: `skimage.io.imread` returns RGB images, you can use that without any conversions needed.